# Как редактировать mp3 tags в android

Tags: java, android, поиск-библиотек, mp3

Подскажите либу для андроид, с помощью которой я бы смог редактировать теги песен.

Answer (score 1):

Покопавшись в тырынете я нашёл ту самую либу, которую искал. Это была mp3agic